# onActivityForResult() is not called in the activity in tabs

Tags: android

I have a tabActivity which has 3 tabs and 3 different activities in each tab.
one of those three activity calls an intent with action pick. but it never returns in onActivityResult() of that activity..

This works fine with simple Activity but doesn't work in Activity called by TabActivity.

Please Help.
Thank You.

I have mainActivity as Tab Activity. In which I has written,

```
mTabHost = getTabHost();
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, A.class);
    StickyTabs.setTab(intent, TAB_INDEX_CALL);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("A")      
            .setIndicator(null,
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon))
            .setContent(intent));
```

same for other 2 tabs.

now I call an Intent in class A. and expecting result in onActivityResult of Class A.

Comment: Maybe some code? What you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, please try: 
YourActivity.this.getParent().startActivityForResult( intent, RESULT_FIRST_USER); 
and do the job in your ActivityGroup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You mean to say, I should write onActivityResult () in parent Activity?

Comment: Yes.
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
  {
   //forwarding to your activity here

  }
  else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
  {
   //forwarding to your activity here
  }

  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

 }

Comment: Thanks Hai Bo Wang. 1 question, Will the View of the inner Activity remain in front?

Comment: set your activity as singletask.    android:launchMode="singleTask" in AndroidManifest.xml. it will remain in front(did not die).

Comment: How do I pass the result to inner activity?